# Is it possible to only deploy the changed files to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk application instead of uploading my whole source code?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up an Elastic Beanstalk Application in AWS.

Until now I have deployed newer versions of my source code (ZIP-file) via the web interface of AWS.

Now my website is online and users are able to upload profile pictures. The problem is when I deploy a new version of my website all my source code will be replaced by the new one and all the user images are gone...

So is there any option to commit only the changed files instead of uploading the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to use a storage solution, such as [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the image files. This way the files will not disappear whenever your application is (re)deployed, and they will be available from all EC2 instances, so your application can scale up and down freely.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you can use the `format-patch` to generate the diff and then upload it and apply it on your server.

```
# generate the patch for the given last X commit
git format-patch HEAD~X
```

Once you have the files upload them to the server and apply them to your code.

If you don't have git installed on your remote server you it a simple Unix patch without the `git apply`

Its very simply and you can see some examples here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/

Comment: I just tried this and can confirm this does not apply to a application running on ElasticBeanstalk.